# Centralize vertically a text and an image inside a <a> element

Tags: html, css

My simple HTML:

```
<a>
    <span>My Text</span>
    <img src="" width="50" height="50" />
</a>
```

My CSS:

```
a {
    padding: 6px;
}
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/sa3LT/

Hi everybody!!

I'm having a trouble with this question. Is simple, I think, but for me I don't find a resolution for this problem.

Tks for all.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sa3LT/1/

Comment: I was going to post that as my answer, but you beat me to it.  Although I would suggest using `a img` instead of just `img` for the css selector.

Comment: @Smeegs good call. Even though it is not necessary for the fiddle, it may cause issues with the rest of his CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the text in the `a` tag to be vertically centered next to the image. Adding this bit of CSS will solve the issue (and as pointed out from Smeegs, this CSS will be for all `img` tags inside an `a` block:

```
a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/sa3LT/1/